# NSData json error

Tags: php, json, swift

In my programm I am using this code to get json from server:

```
func getJSON(urlToRequest: String) -> NSData{
    return NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlToRequest)!)!
}
```

urlToRequest is creating using information from form, so the problem is if I enter only English letters in form and I get urlToRequest like:

`"http://example.com/join?joinName=Max&joinEmail=my@email.com&joinPass=myPass&joinBirth=01.01.1990&joinGender=1"` everything is works, but if I put for example Russian letters in form and get link:

`"http://example.com/join?joinName=Максим&joinEmail=my@email.com&joinPass=myPass&joinBirth=01.01.1990&joinGender=1"`

I get error with NSData `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Please, help, how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` to sanitize your URL:

```
let str = "http://example.com/join?joinName=Максим&joinEmail=my@email.com&joinPass=myPass&joinBirth=01.01.1990&joinGender=1"

let url = NSURL(string: str.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet())!)
```